# Website detects devtools. Code is attached of DevToolDectect.js file from the website sources

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am not a developer and have very basic understanding for Javascript code. I am trying to open dev tools on a website but it detects that dev tools have been opened and gives a popup written "DevTools detected", and then closes the website tab after I press ok. This is the file in the sources named DevToolDetect.js. I am trying to understand how does it detect that devtools have been opened even when the menu is undocked. If there is a problem in the question, kindly tell so I can give any required imformation needed.
I don't need a line by line explanation, just a summary will do.
Thanks!

```
/*!
devtools-detect
Detect if DevTools is open
https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect
By Sindre Sorhus
MIT License
*/
(function () {
    'use strict';

    const devtools = {
        isOpen: false,
        orientation: undefined
    };

    const threshold = 160;

    const emitEvent = (isOpen, orientation) => {
        window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('devtoolschange', {
            detail: {
                isOpen,
                orientation
            }
        }));
    };

    const main = ({emitEvents = true} = {}) => {
        const widthThreshold = window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth > threshold;
        const heightThreshold = window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight > threshold;
        const orientation = widthThreshold ? 'vertical' : 'horizontal';

        if (
            !(heightThreshold && widthThreshold) &&
            ((window.Firebug && window.Firebug.chrome && window.Firebug.chrome.isInitialized) || widthThreshold || heightThreshold)
        ) {
            if ((!devtools.isOpen || devtools.orientation !== orientation) && emitEvents) {
                emitEvent(true, orientation);
            }

            devtools.isOpen = true;
            devtools.orientation = orientation;
        } else {
            if (devtools.isOpen && emitEvents) {
                emitEvent(false, undefined);
            }

            devtools.isOpen = false;
            devtools.orientation = undefined;
        }
    };

    main({emitEvents: false});
    setInterval(main, 500);

    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
        module.exports = devtools;
    } else {
        window.devtools = devtools;
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like historically grown heuristic try & error for non-Chrome browsers and utilising `devtools` object for Chrome based browsers.

For non-Chrome it does some guesswork by calculating if there is a part of the browser window that does not display a web page and might be big enough for hosting devtools, and it also checks for traces of [Firebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_(software)), the glorious godfather of any sensible devtools, though there is very, very low probability to still find it nowaddays.

In a short test with Chrome, this script was not able to detect a detached devtools window.

Feel invited to get into depth with these hints. You might learn a lot, considering not at least that this is a Sindre Sorhus script, the [man with the most npm packages and GitHub repos](https://sindresorhus.com/about) mankind is aware of.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am finally able to prevent the website from detecting DevTools (undocked). Before whenever I opened devtools, I got an overlay saying paused in debugger nomatter whether the devtools were docked or undocked. The solution was to press ctrl+f8(shortcut key to deactivate breakpoints) before the devtools get fully loaded. If I wait for devtools to load completely, the overlay appears again, after pressing  resume script execution the website tab closes itself after pooping up a message "Devtools detected". Don't why it works but it works.